# css toggle switch - add transition for background-color between pseudo elements

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've made a switch-toggle checkbox with pure css, [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/LQFtF/6/).

Now I want to animate it with some transition - (have the background slide right and left, like it does [here](http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/)). But I'm really not sure how (that example I linked uses different html, and I don't plan to change mine).

I tried to do something like this:

```
@keyframes goleft {
  0%   { margin-right: 10px; text-indent: 10px; }
  50%  { margin-right: 22px; text-indent: 22px; }
  100% { margin-right: 35px; text-indent: 35px; }
}

// later: 
transition: goleft 1s infinite;
```

`35px` is half the width of the entire box, I thought the background would move but the text would stay, and I'd make another animation for the other direction. But it didn't work.

I'm pretty new to creating animations\transitions with css3, any suggestions?

**p.s.** as mentioned, I don't want to change my html there, and I don't want to use javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FIXED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LQFtF/7/)

I add a little changes in code :
- I move the text to spans, and used the before element for the background of moving with transition.

[you can see the fixed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LQFtF/7/)

```
label{
    position:relative;    
}

.switchbox input + label:before {
    transition:0.3s;
    content:""; display:block;
    width:50%;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  background: #a5a5a5; /* W3C */    
}

.switchbox input:checked + label:before {
    left:50%; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing that - but the opposite way around (adding a span for the background instead of the text). [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/LQFtF/9/)